# Customizing the display name of an outgoing noreply email

Tags: .net, outlook, exchange-server, .net-4.5, smtpclient

I am setting up a handful of .net applications to use an authenticated noreply mailbox on Exchange for all outgoing system-generated e-mail (notifications, etc).

The sysadmins set up the mailbox and a user to authenticate and I am correctly able to send emails using the SmtpClient class; everything is working smoothly.

Unfortunately, I have a requirement to change the Display Name of the user to something that allows the receiving user to understand which particular software is sending the notification, i.e. to setup rules etc.

For example, I would like to send as:

- NoReply Service1 <noreply@domain.com>
- NoReply Service2 <noreply@domain.com>

Etc.

I thought it would be quite simple, as the MailAddress class has a DisplayName property that I can set with different values for every system and it actually works for mail that leaves my organization, i.e. when the recipient email address is an external Gmail contact.

Unfortunately, it does not seem to work for users that are using Outlook inside my organization - in this case Outlook shows the Display Name for the owner of the mailbox. It shouldn't be a client cache problem because it also shows up with the mailbox Display Name in OWA.

I have checked the From headers of the delivered message and it contains my customized display name, so Exchange shouldn't be at fault.

Also, the noreply mailbox isn't advertised in the Global Address List so it shouldn't be picking up that name from there.

Any clues on how I can force Outlook to use the from display name I set?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Each Exchange mailbox has only one display name - you can't change it on the fly. Try to send as an address that is not linked with any Exchange mailbox.